# Load RSA public key created in JSBN, then encrypt a message

Tags: javascript, c++, encryption, rsa, crypto++

I am trying to create a RSA key pair in JavaScript using [JSBN](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn) and transfer the public key to Crypto++. Then, I am trying to encrypt a message in Crypto++ and send it back to JavaScript and decrypt it.

But I am relatively new at this, so I think I am doing something wrong ( data is not getting decrypted ofc )

any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Here is my cpp code

```
Integer n(nStr->c_str()),
e("0x10001");

RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
pubKey.Initialize(n, e);

AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
if (!pubKey.Validate(rng, 3))
    throw std::exception("Rsa private key validation failed");

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Encryption
RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor enc(pubKey);
StringSource ss1(data, true,
        new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, enc,
            new StringSink(retStr)
        ));

std::string retData2 = "";

StringSource ss2((const byte*)retStr.data(), retStr.size(), true,
        new Base64Encoder(
            new StringSink(retData2)
        ));

retStr = retData2;
```

And my javascript code

```
// nStr in CPP is "0x" + localStorage.getItem("rsa_public")  from javascript
// data in CPP is "secret"

var rsa = new RSAKey();
var publickey = localStorage.getItem("rsa_public");
var privatekey = localStorage.getItem("rsa_private");
rsa.setPrivate(publickey, "10001", privatekey);
alert(b64tohex(dec) + "\n" + rsa.encrypt("secret")); <-- these don't match at all .. and ofc rsa.decrypt returns null
```

dec in javascript is retStr from CPP

Comment: Which Javascript library are you using?` RSAKey` is not in the ECMAScript built-ins library.

Comment: using http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn

Comment: @2340C -please post a copy of the key pair, and a sample message encrypted under the public key. Be sure they are encoded using what comes out of Javascript and JSBN. (I'm a Crypto++ guy, so I'll be able to test it from the Crypto++ side of things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PKCS#1 v1.5 Padding that is used by JSBN and your Crypto++ code is a random padding, so if you encrypt data with the same key it will look differently. You have to check whether your implementation works by encrypting on one end and decrypting on the other in both directions.

Comment: This answer only examines the difference between encrytion with cryptopp and encryption with jsbn presumably with the same public key. Since I'm not a C++ programmer, I have no idea what further problems there might be. If you can provide a more complete answer, I welcome you to post your own. I don't mind getting unaccepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor enc(pubKey);
StringSource ss1(data, true,
        new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, enc,
            new StringSink(retStr)
        ));
...
StringSource ss2((const byte*)retStr.data(), retStr.size(), true,
        new Base64Encoder(
            new StringSink(retData2)
        ));
```

I'm not sure this is correct *for interop'ing with Javascript and JSBN*. It is correct stand alone, and it is correct for interop'ing with OpenSSL.

Crypto++ uses an early Base64 encoding scheme. It was seen in email and other standards of the time (the time was around the 1990s). The alphabet uses the plus (+) and forward slash (/) characters.

The Javascript and JSON technologies like JSON Web Keys (JWKs) tend to favor the Base64 encoding using the URL or Web Safe alphabet. The alphabet uses the minus (-) and underscore (_) characters.

Both the old and new Base64 encoding schemes are specified in [RFC 4648, The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648).

You should fetch the patch for the [Base64URLEncoder](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64URLEncoder), and apply it in-place over top of the Crypto++ sources. After you patch, you will have the existing `Base6Encoder` and the new `Base64URLEncoder`. Finally, recompile and reinstall the library. You have to patch it because its not part of the Crypto++ library as written and offered by Wei Dai.

Then, do the following:

```
RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor enc(pubKey);
string encoded;

StringSource ss(data, true,
        new PK_EncryptorFilter(prng, enc,
            new Base64URLEncoder(
                new StringSink(encoded)
        )));

// Print encoded cipher text
cout << encoded << endl;

return encoded;
```

As for *"these don't match at all..."* - I think that's expected. RSA encryption uses randomized padding so that when you encrypt messages *`m1`* and *`m2`*, the cipher text is different. Its called "semantic security" and its a strong (stronger?) notion of security. This way, the bad guy can't tell when the same message has been sent twice.

Comment: Crypto++ and the javascript rsa sdk by Tom Wu , they both support interop'ing with OpenSSL. that is why I went with those choices , an also I might have to support more kinds of clients in the future